# order of calling constructor in inheritance

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor, destructor

I am new to C++ programming language, i have a confusion about order of calling the constructor in inheritance. my question is even though the constructor and destructor are not inherited by derived class why the base class constructor will call when i create a derived class object.

Comment: Do you want to know why they are called, or in what order they are called?

Comment: You may want to check whether the answer has already been given, e.g. in this post: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247595/order-of-calling-base-class-constructor-from-derived-class-initializer-list

Comment: @ jogojapan : yeah i want to know why base class constructor will call if i create a derived class object.

Comment: @skjaidev : yeah googled but didn't get perfect answer why base class constructor call when i create a derived class object even though base class constructors not inherited by derived class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The purpose of a constructor is to define how the data members should be initialised. Since a derived class inherits the data members from the base class, any constructor of the derived class must define not only how to initialise the data members that are specific to the derived class, but also those coming from the base class.

The natural way to do this (and required by the C++ Standard) is by calling a base class constructor. If you don't include a specific constructor call in the initialization list for your derived-class constructor, the default constructor of the base class will be used to initialise the base-class members.

```
struct base
{
   int _i;               // a data member
   base():_i(0) {}       // default constructor
   base(int i):_i(i) {}  // special constructor
};

struct derived : base
{
  int _j;                         // a data member specific to the derived class
  derived(int i, int j):_j(j) {}  // user-defined constructor for the derived class
};
```

The example above illustrates how the derived-class constructor can initialise its member `_j`, but the member `_i`, coming from the base class, must be initialised using a base-class constructor.

The way it's written above, the default constructor `base::base()` will be automatically called by the compiler, i.e. `_i` will be initialised to 0.

But you can change that behaviour by including a call to a specific constructor:

```
struct derived : base
{
  int _j;
  derived(int i, int j):base(i),_j(j) {}  // user-defined constructor for the derived class
};
```

The order of the constructor calls is: First constructor calls of the base class, then initializers for the derived-class specific members. This is only natural because the derived class, in a sense, is an *extension* of the base class, and it makes sense to regard the base-class part of the derived-class object as *being there first*.

Comment: okay but private data members not inherited by derived class na at that situation also base constructor is called why ..

Comment: @nagaradderKantesh Private data members are also inherited. They are just not accessible for derived-class member functions.