# c++ Virtual/Non-virtual Diamond inheritance

Tags: c++, virtual-inheritance, diamond-problem

Given the following code in C++:

```
struct A {
    A() { f(0); }
    A(int i) { f(i); }
    virtual void f(int i) { cout << i; }
};
struct B1 : virtual A {
    B1(int i) : A(i) { f(i); }
    virtual void f(int i) { cout << i+10; }
};
struct B2 : virtual A {
    B2(int i) : A(i) { f(i); }
    virtual void f(int i) { cout << i+20; }
};
struct C : B1, virtual B2 {
    int i;
    C() : B1(6),B2(3),A(1){}
    virtual void f(int i) { cout << i+30; }
};
```

Can someone explain why `C* c = new C()`; will print 1 23 and then 16 in that order? How does it decide which order to print in? I know that the nonvirtual `B1` will be called last but why is `A()` called first? Thanks for the help and explanation ahead of time.

Comment: `A` is a base of `B2`, so it has to be constructed before `B2`.

Comment: Duplicates of: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247595/order-of-calling-base-class-constructor-from-derived-class-initialization-list and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2669888/c-initialization-order-for-member-classes ?  If you look up initialization order of base classes, you'll find plenty of reading material :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because your are virtually inheriting `B2`, the compiler will construct it first as to identify which variables are virtually inherited in `C` before it constructs any non-virtual inheritance (`B1`).  Of course, `A` gets constructed first because `B2` needs it before it can be constructed.