# How to remind a param passed to the base class constructor?

Tags: c++, constructor

Having a member and pass the same to the base class works if:

```
DerrivedClass::DerrivedClass(SomeParamType* p)
    : BaseClass(p),
      derrivedClassMember(p),
{
 ...
}
```

... but how to share without passing it as param to the DerrivedClass constructor? Is this valid? Or is the derrivedClassMember not initialized at this time?

```
DerrivedClass::DerrivedClass()
    : BaseClass(derrivedClassMember),
      derrivedClassMember(new SomeParamType()),
{
 ...
}
```

I'm not able to change the base class implementation.

Comment: So the question is, if the constructors of base classes are executed before the members of derived class are initialized.

Comment: No, the question is how to pass the same object to the base class constructor and the member object constructor.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is not initialialized at that time. The baseclass constructor is called before the `derrivedClassMember` is initialized. That's because the derived members or the constructor of the derived class may depend on members of the baseclass.

Answer (score 4):

In C++11 you could use a delegating constructor:

```
class Derived : public Base {
public:
    Derived() : Derived(new SomeParamType()) {}
    ...
private:
    Derived(SomeParamType* p) : Base(p), derivedMember(p) {}
};
```

As a side note, I know this is probably just an example but you shouldn't create unmanaged objects on the heap like this in a constructor: if the `Base` constructor throws then you're in for a memory leak. Prefer smart pointers whenever possible.

Comment: +1 I *love* that feature. I just wish the neanderthals at work would get with the times and let us use C++11 in production.

Comment: @WhozCraig I for one kinda "forced it down their throats" by rewriting (on my own free time, mind you) a few chosen critical classes and showing the result. 30% less code, much better readability, enhanced performance thanks to move semantics, and lambda functions made the case for me. You could always try something like this, the benefits were really worth the small waste of my personal free time.

Comment: Oh I've been doing the very same thing, its just sad it has to be so stealth. I really like whats been done to the language, but my god the work-politics can get brutal to gain traction against.

Answer (score 3):

I'm cringing as I write this, but....

```
DerrivedClass::DerrivedClass(SomeParamType* p = new SomeParamType())
    : BaseClass(p),
      derrivedClassMember(p)
{
}
```

I need to go shower now. Regardless, in deference to your question, yes, your base constructor should be executed before your members are initialized. Members have to be initialized in their top-down order, starting with the base members in its constructor and working out.

Note: I'd have to dust off my standard copy to find where this is specified, but I'm fairly sure its in there, as lint *loves* to tell you about out-of-order initialization warnings and their non-compliance.

Comment: Woah, it's ugly, it smells fishy, but I like it!

Comment: **§12.6.2,10** states that the base class constructor *will* (not *should*) be executed before the members are initialized, and that the order of both base classes initializations and member initializations occur explicitly in the order in which they are declared in the class definition. - However, I found a workaround for C++03 that omits the default parameter (see my answer)

Comment: @ArneMertz thanks for the cite. I knew it was in there somewhere; just didn't have the time to hunt it down. when members are *not* explicitly listed in proper decl order on an initializer list lint rings bells and alarms, and with that cite, its pretty obvious why. Thanks again.

Answer (score 2):

To sum up the answers given up to now, and add a bit more, there are a few possible solutions.

**1** If your base class has an accessor for the member, its fairly easy:

```
DerrivedClass::DerrivedClass()
: BaseClass(new SomeParamType()),
  derrivedClassMember(getBaseClassMember()),
{
  ...
}
```

**2** in C++11, use a delegating constructor, calling the original constructor you posted:

```
DerrivedClass::DerrivedClass()
: DerrivedClass(new SomeParamType())
{}
```

**3** in C++03, use a default argument (which is ugly):

```
DerrivedClass::DerrivedClass(SomeParamType* p = new SomeParamType())
    : BaseClass(p),
      derrivedClassMember(p),
{
 ...
}
```

**4** Another workaround, to get rid of the constructor default argument in C++03, would be to use multiple inheritance to get the `derivedclassMember` initialized before the base class:

```
struct DerivedClassInitializationWorkaround {
  SomeParamType* derivedClassMember:
  DerivedClassInitializationWorkaround(SomeParamType* param) 
    : derivedClassMember(param) {}
};

class DerivedClass : private DerivedClassInitializationWorkaround, //this has to go first!
                     public BaseClass {
public:
  DerivedClass::DerivedClass()
    : DerivedClassInitializationWorkaround(new SomeParamType())
    , BaseClass(derivedClassMember)
  {}
};
```

The initialization of base classes occurs in the order of their declaration, so if you derive from `DerivedClassInitializationWorkaround`, the `derivedClassMember` it contains gets initialized first.

In any cases, your code is not exception safe. You should not store owning pointers as raw pointers but use smart pointers. Since you can't change the base class, you will have to determine if it takes ownership of the object (i.e. if it destroys the object you pass to its constructor.

If the base class object takes ownership, you are more or less stuck with the existing solutions, except that your derived class should store a *reference* instead of the pointer, because the base class object and therfore the `SomeParamType` object will outlive the derived class' object.

If the base class does not take ownership, you should store a `unique_ptr`:

```
class DerivedClass : public BaseClass {
  unique_ptr<SomeParamType> derivedClassMember;

  DerivedClass::DerivedClass(unique_ptr<SomeParamType> param)
    : BaseClass(param.get())
    , derivedClassMember(move(param))
  {}

public:
  DerivedClass::DerivedClass()
    : DerivedClass(make_unique<SomeParamType>)
  {}
};
```

Comment: Nice C++03 workaround. It's sad that it has to be so convoluted, but at least the public interface is much cleaner (and more importantly less error prone) than the "default argument" method so I guess the end justifies the means. :)

Answer (score 1):

Short answer is no, it is not valid.

Here's a good answer to your question:

[Order of calling base class constructor from derived class initialization list](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6247595/order-of-calling-base-class-constructor-from-derived-class-initialization-list)